# Subquery returned more than 1 value how to get this data

Tags: sql

I have one order order have a lot of articles and 2 articles have same color i can get color_no from color where order_id is ican put when i can below query execute thie error shown Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. i know that duplicate record there but i need this data //select all color which order_id is given in below query if duplicate no problem show the colors:

```
select color_no from color
where color_id=(select trans_id from transaction_order
where order_id=(select order_id from master_order where program_no='13-065454'))
```

Comment: would you please add input data and expected output in table format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you get wrong id

`where color_id=(select trans_id ......)`

You try this

`color_id=(select color_id from transaction_order where order_id=(select order_id from master_order where program_no='13-065454'))`

Comment: thanks a lot @naeemshah1 its work its little mistake in my code thanks for correct me

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you need "in":

```
SELECT color_no 
FROM   color 
WHERE  color_id IN (SELECT trans_id 
                    FROM   transaction_order 
                    WHERE  order_id IN (SELECT order_id 
                                        FROM   master_order 
                                        WHERE  program_no = '13-065454'))
```

Comment: Then you need to debug your query. Try selecting subqueries one by one: `select .... where program_no = '...'` to see if it returns anything and if it's what you expect to see. Then add another layer, etc.

Comment: select trans_id from transaction_order where order_id=(select order_id from master_order where program_no='13-065454')   this was return me 2 trans_id

Comment: and every trans_id have color_id but these 2 trans_id have same color_id so how to get this id and show his name

Comment: um... according to your query trans_id should be the same as color_id.
`in` or `=` expects to have exact match. If you need to find colors corresponding to trans_id - you need to `select color_id(or whatever the column name is)` instead of `select trans_id`

Comment: user input program_no i can find the program no of colors and color aur relationship between transaction table and program in master table and transaction tabel relationship betweeen master table